# I tried to run this but I get an error "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

The error occurs here:

```
CREATE TABLE CERDIT_CARD_LOG
(
    CERDIT_CARD_NUMBER     CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CERDIT_CARD_LOG_NUMBER CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CERDIT_CARD_NUM        CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DATE                   DATE     NOT NULL,
    OPERATION_TYPE         CHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_CERDIT_CARD_LOG 
        PRIMARY KEY (CERDIT_CARD_LOG_NUMBER, CERDIT_CARD_NUM)
);

ALTER TABLE CERDIT_CARD_LOG
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CERDIT_C_RECORD_CERDIT_C 
            FOREIGN KEY (CERDIT_CARD_NUMBER)
                    REFERENCES CERDIT_CARD (CERDIT_CARD_NUMBER);
```

Comment: A foreign key must reference a whole key. In this case two columns, not just one.

Comment: It's a **credit card** - not a "cerdit card" ....

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved word, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Either chose something else, or delimit as `"DATE"`.

Comment: Just change it to `CREDIT_CARD_DATE`.  Also search and replace "CERDIT" with "CREDIT".

Comment: As mentioned, you should call this date different. This will even clarify what the date is about. Is it the card's `EXPIRATION_DATE` maybe? And, on a side note, you should never use `CHAR`. This data type is a nuisance to work with in queries and has no advantage over `VARCHAR2` in any regard.

Comment: @jarlh: The foreign key references the table CREDIT_CARD, the structure of which we don't see here. I assume that its complete primary key is indeed the single CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes, now I see... my bad,

Comment: Also by the way, `char` is not a useful type in Oracle and is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a column with the name `DATE` in Oracle (reserved word) you need to treat it as a special identifier, and enclose it in double quotes.

You can do:

```
create table CERDIT_CARD_LOG
(
    CERDIT_CARD_NUMBER      CHAR(20)               not null,
    CERDIT_CARD_LOG_NUMBER  CHAR(15)               not null,
    CERDIT_CARD_NUM         CHAR(20)               not null,
    "DATE"                    DATE                   not null,
    OPERATION_TYPE          CHAR(20)               not null,
  constraint PK_CERDIT_CARD_LOG primary key (CERDIT_CARD_LOG_NUMBER,CERDIT_CARD_NUM  )
);
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f18ccb14fe1e9881a842cc1aec9e6f1).

**Note**: As you see it's possible to use reserved words. I personally avoid it since I would need to remember to enclose them in double quotes in every single query I write in the future. I typically prefer change its name to `opened_on` or similar.